# How to pass an array params to other screen via Modal

Tags: react-native

To call other screen with params, we use like -

```
navigation.navigate('Editcustomer', {customerdt: customerdt})
```

I used the same for the Mobile screen and its working fine.

For Tablet screen, I need to show the same `Editcustomer` screen as a `Modal`, for that I use like -

```
<Modal
    animationType="slide"
    transparent={true}
    visible={modalVisibleProd}>
    <View
      style={[
        global.commonModalbg,
        {justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'},
      ]}>
      <View style={[global.modalBoxscreeen, global.commonBoxshadow]}>
        <Editcustomer
          navigation={navigation}
          route={customerdt} // how to pass params
          onClosemodel={onClosemodel}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  </Modal>
```

**Editcustomer.js**

This screen received a navigation and params

```
export default function Editcustomer({navigation, route}) {
```

NOTE : Without params I did the same for other screen for Mobile and reuse the same for Table and its working good.

How to pass params to screen via `Modal`?

Answer (score 1):

Since your EditCustomer is a screen and you are not really navigating to it in your modal, just rendering it, you can pass the parameters as props, here is an example:

```
export default function Editcustomer(props) {
   
   return(
      // WHAT YOU ARE RENDERING
      <Text>{props.text}</Text>
   )
}
```

And to pass the props, in your case you would do:

```
<Modal
    animationType="slide"
    transparent={true}
    visible={modalVisibleProd}>
    <View
      style={[
        global.commonModalbg,
        {justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'},
      ]}>
      <View style={[global.modalBoxscreeen, global.commonBoxshadow]}>
        <Editcustomer
          text={"MY TEXT"}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  </Modal>
```

This will achieve what you want and you can then use whatever logic you have in Editcustomer inside the modal, since I do not have your Editcustomer screen you will have to adapt this example to your case. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am using navigation to Editcustomer.js in Phone and need to show the same Editcustomer.js as modal for Tablet. Issue on passing the params(array) as Modal for Tab

Comment: navigation.navigate('Editcustomer', {customerdt: customerdt})

Comment: I know, the issue here is that to show it as a modal you can't navigate to it, since the modal is wrapping it on the other view, what you can do however is either what I showed above or just placing the modal inside and wrapping the whole EditCustomer screen instead. EDIT: The last option isn't viable because then you would need to have something to show the modal in the other page instead, i suggest you try the example featured above. You will still be passing the parameters as props.